# dantelogo.sty missing

Tags: packages

I have a Latex template which I need to follow, however, when I am compiling it to obtain the pdf I am getting the error: "LaTeX Error: File `dantelogo.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. \RequirePackage" What can be the issue?

Comment: You can get it here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dantelogo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please name the template you use and give us a link to it if possible. Seems it calls a package 'dantelogo'.

Comment: It is in TeX Live 2014....

Comment: Are you *completely* sure that you have to use this logo?? DANTE is the german LaTeX User Group.

Comment: I already downloaded it but it is not working still. I am trying to compile the given template as it is, it was given by out university not online so I cannot give a link.

Comment: Comment out the package, i think you are not using it as it is very unlikely that you are typesetting the logo. You can install the package via the package manager of your distribution. The package contains font which have to be introduced to your system properly. Just copying files won't do this time.

Comment: If you are interested in discussion LaTeX topics in german, feel free to visit goLaTeX.de or TeXwelt.de.

Comment: which command produces this error? I can remove that line maybe

Comment: Comment out `\usepackage{dantelogo}`!

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: I commented out the line you told me :)

Comment: Can you give me a pointer where to get to the template or how to contact the maintainer?

Answer (score 1):

Package `dantelogo` is needed to typeset the logo of DANTE, (Deutschsprachige Anwendervereinigung TeX e.V.). It is unlikely that you need the actual logo, comment out the line.

A short pointer where to get the template or how to get hold of the maintainer would be nice.